# How to 'click' radix ui react dropdown menu using Selenium IDE

Tags: reactjs, selenium-ide, radix-ui

I am testing the website I created using Selenium IDE. I use React as the frontend, but now I'm having a problem with one of the libraries I used, particularly the Radix UI React Dropdown Menu. I recorded the part of clicking the button, which is supposed to show the dropdown popup, but nothing happened after I played back the recording, the button has been clicked but the dropdown didn't show up.

I also tried typing 'document.getElementById(element's id)' in the console just to check if my locator is correct, and it returns the element. I also attempted to click the button using 'document.getElementById(element's id).click()', but nothing happened as well. I'm not sure if I'm targeting the right element, since when I manually the button (not programmatically or using Selenium), it works.

I can't post the website I created as it hasn't been published yet, but the same behavior applies when I tried Selenium IDE on their docs example: https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/dropdown-menu.